# Quick and easy GUI programming in Linux

Tags: linux, user-interface, scripting

There is GTK in C/C++ and QT in C++. But, I don't want to use C/C++; is there a way to write GUI's in Linux using scripting languages? If so which scripting language and which bindings?

Note: I've intentially not mentioned a preferred scripting language because I don't want responses geared towards one language. Any scripting language will do.

Comment: More or less any scripting language and more or less any graphics library. Just search for the combination you want (such as [Perl GTK](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=perl+gtk)).

Comment: You are making the hypothesis that GUI programming can always be made "quick and easy"; I am not exactly sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

Python has `tkinter`, which is pretty straightforward. There's also `PyGTK` and `wxWidgets`, which are more powerful but less pythonic.

If you don't want to learn the internals of these toolkits, you can always just use them to render a `WebView` and `HTML/CSS` your way out of the problem. Your GUI won't have a native feel, though.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way is using [TK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_%28framework%29). TK started as part of TCL, but there are bindings for most of the popular scripting languages (Perl, Ruby, Python and, of course, TCL, to mention a few). TK is so prevalent that it's hard to think of anything else, really, in that domain. It's very well designed, and the concepts it popularized have wound their way into most GUI toolkits.

If you're comfortable with Java, you may want to check out Scala, as well (Scala can be used as a scripting language).

Comment: IMHO, TK is really outdated, and I won't recommend it to a newbie.